# Android Maps V2 on Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread

Tags: android-maps-v2

I have a big problem with run simple sample code on my **xperia neo v cell (android v 2.3.4)**.
I had import android-support-v4.jar and added google-play-services_lib to project library.
Please send me some issue what can solve my problem.
My problem look like this:

```
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.googleMapApp/com.googleMapApp.LocationProfileManagerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googleMapApp.LocationProfileManagerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.googleMapApp-1.apk]
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googleMapApp.LocationProfileManagerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.googleMapApp-1.apk]
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
02-24 23:27:34.183: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    ... 11 more
```

My manifest file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googleMapApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.googleMapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.googleMapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Require OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationProfileManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

My Main.java file:

```
  package com.example.googlemapapp;


import com.googleMapApp.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity);
    }

}
```

Layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to manifest, your **LAUNCHER Activity** is LocationProfileManagerActivity. But your class is Main.java.
So, Rename **Main.java** to **LocationProfileManagerActivity.java** and don't forget to change the class name also.
Check it